# Was Gozo Shioda influenced by Kimura & Oyama?

Tags: aikido, history

I ask because my understanding is that [Shioda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gozo_Shioda)'s [Yoshinkan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshinkan) school of Aikido was considered controversial in that it recognized the brutality of combat, when one is fighting for one's life, and emphasized techniques such as strikes, which can be said to go against Ueshiba's principle of peace.

It is well known that [Kimura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masahiko_Kimura) was [Oyama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mas_Oyama)'s good friend and sparring partner, but all three masters were at Takushoku University at the same time, and Shioda took Judo classes with them.

Where is there is a confluence of three great masters at one time and place, it seems likely that they exchanged ideas.

> Shioda viewed aikido as being "not a sport but a budo. Either you defeat your opponent or he defeats you. You cannot complain that he did not follow the rules. You have to overcome your opponent in a way appropriate to each situation."